# Gimbal Rotation - withCompletion method fired before rotation completes

Tags: dji-sdk

When rotating the gimbal in a virtual stick mission with rotateWithRotation it seems like the completion function fires before the gimbal has finished pitching to the desired degree. Is this expected? Looking at the examples of Virtual stick on the SDK docs it seems like sleep or NSTimer are used quite a lot to alleviate these scenarios. Seems a bit hacky. Is there a better way to know when the gimbal has actually completed rotating?

For example I want to shoot a photo once gimbal rotation has completed like below.

```c
DJIGimbalRotation *rotation = [DJIGimbalRotation gimbalRotationWithPitchValue:-90 rollValue:0 yawValue:0 time:2 mode:DJIGimbalRotationModeAbsoluteAngle ignore:NO];
DJIGimbal *gimbal = [DJISDKManager product].gimbal;
[gimbal rotateWithRotation:rotation completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Rotate Gimbal Failed: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.description]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Rotating Gimbal Completed");
            NSLog(@"About to shoot photo");
            [camera startShootPhotoWithCompletion:nil];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used the DJI SDK, and this would not be a very elegant solution, but I wonder if you could write some code in the state callback for the gimbal to track the pitch of the gimbal and trigger an action once the gimbal's pitch stops changing? https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Gimbal/DJIGimbal.html#djigimbal_setgimbalstateupdatecallback_inline

Answer (score 0):

I used it correctly without any problem, try to elaborate your code as mine and try again. Note this code is being triggered by the "progressed" case when starting a waypoint mission within the timeline action elements

Try also change the ignore parameter to "Yes"

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            let gimbal = fetchGimbal()
            gimbal?.rotate(with: DJIGimbalRotation(pitchValue: -45, rollValue: 0, yawValue: 0, time: 2, mode: .absoluteAngle, ignore: true), completion: { (error) in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("Error", error as Any)
                    } else {
                        print("Gimabl has moved or is moving!")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```